# How to replace lookbehind PHP structure of Regex into Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, regex, validation

I have built Regex which is working properly with php , but not working in Javascript due to Invalid group structure error.

I know it is because Javascript does not support Lookbehind expressions. I tried to convert it but not able to do so.

Regex link : https://regex101.com/r/bC4hN2/1

Regex Expression : **(?<=^| )(.\d+)?(?=$| )|(?<=^| ).\d+(?=$| )**

Acceptance Criteria : Values should lie between 0 and 1 and should start with decimal point

**Valid entries**

- .20
- 0
- 1
- .1

**Invalid Entries**

- 1.20
- 1.0
- 0.20
- 2

This scenarios working properly with PHP Regex Expression , but not with Javascript due to errors.

How should i convert it to Javascript OR any alternate expression to achieve my scenario ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you need a regex for this? Why not convert the value to a float and check it's between 0 and 1

Comment: Example of _Regex Overkill_?

Comment: Yes, I need regex for this.(Not good in regex) I tried several but not able to achieve my scenario. I built above by combining two i found online. But it is working in PHP and not in Javascript.

Comment: [I have a problem](http://i2.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/495/274/3f5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done easily as mentioned in comments but let's modify your regex. (*Your match is in first capturing group*)

```
(?:\s|^)([01]\b|(?:\.\d+))(?=\s|$)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aT4oR1/2)**

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked perfectly. I have been trying this since yesterday. I tried a lot to learn Regex while working on this issue, but it doesn't goes into my head.. Damn!